# How make query to Tensorflow Inception Serving model from deployed in gcloud, in Nodejs

Tags: gcloud, tensorflow-serving

I would like query a tensorflow inception fine tuned model from a web server that I have deployed on gcloud / kubernet by following the official tutorial https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception.html.

I completed all steps and locally I can make query to the distant server `$ bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client --server=146.148.88.232:9000 --image=/path/to/my_cat_image.jpg`
.

I dont understand how could I query server from a webserver (nodejs, Rails, flask..).

Answer (score 1):

You should build a gRPC client to query the gRPC server.

Here is a sample building a gRPC in nodejs.

[gRPC sample nodejs](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/node.html)

[Demo](https://github.com/clarle/node-tensorflow-serving-demo)